# flex-slider on safari web browser, you-tube content is present although it's not the active slide

Tags: safari, flexslider

I'm using flexslider in my website, all slides have you-tube content and some text,

all browsers works great with my slider, but i'm having a weird problem in safari.

the problem is, that all you-tube's content are shown (without the text) although, they are not the active slide.

a little bit of explanation:
I mean that when the slider is shown, I can see the current you-tube, in the middle (the active slide) and also the previous and the next you-tube in the left and the right side.

I have tried to look for any kind of solution to this problem, but with no success.

my slider configuration:

```
$('#contentSlider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshow: false,
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    video:true,
    controlsContainer: ".sliderContainer",
    before: window.ozcode.carouselManager.beforeSlide,
    after: window.ozcode.carouselManager.afterSlide,
});
```

Thanks,

NadavSt.